# IQueryable returning nulls, IEnumerable does not

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, dto, iqueryable

I have an extension method that needs to return some DTOs based on an `IQueryable` it receives. Tinkering with the code today (I added a new `int` property) I realized the method was not working properly anymore, returning part of the DTOs list as nulls.

I wanted to see if maybe a property I added was the problem so I trimmed the method to how it looks below and it stills returns some nulls.

```
public static IQueryable<OperationDto> SelectDto(this IQueryable<Operation> operations)
{
    return operations.Select(op=> new OperationDto
        {
            Id = op.Id
        });
}
```

I changed the method to

```
public static IEnumerable<OperationDto> SelectDto(this IQueryable<Operation> operations)
{
    return operations.AsEnumerable().Select(op=> new OperationDto
        {
            Id = op.Id
        });
}
```

and it works again without changing anything else.

I don't understand why the `IQueryable<OperationDto>` suddenly stopped working (maybe the new property) and why the `IEnumerable` variant works.

**EDIT**

The extension method is called in the following repository method:

- original IQueryable version:

  ```
  public IQueryable<OperationDto> FindOperationDtos(OperationModelFilter modelFilter)
  {
      IQueryable<Operation> filteredData = DbSet.AsQueryable();

      if (modelFilter.UserId.HasValue)
          filteredData = filteredData.Where(o => o.User.Id == modelFilter.UserId.Value);

      ...

      return filteredData.Distinct().SelectDto();
  }
  ```
- IEnumerable version:

  ```
  public IQueryable<OperationDto> FindOperationDtos(OperationModelFilter modelFilter)
  {
       IQueryable<Operation> filteredData = DbSet.AsQueryable();

       if (modelFilter.UserId.HasValue)
           filteredData = filteredData.Where(o => o.User.Id == modelFilter.UserId.Value);

       ...

       return filteredData.Distinct().SelectDto();
  }
  ```

Comment: What's the origin of `operations`?

Comment: When I tried to use `Select` with `IQueryable`, I got the same. The problem is, that you need to use `Select` only with the final result of your operations, means with `IEnumerable`, because `IQueryable` stores only commands how to get data. So, I advice you to use `Select` only with `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @GertArnold Explained the call for the extension method.

Comment: @YuriyN. I use Select with IQueryable in other extension methods and they seem to work fine. Maybe it's something specific to this situation...

Comment: Are you sure that you have your new column `Id` in corresponding table in database?

Comment: @YuriyN. The `Id` column is the PK of the table. That is why I reduced the entire code to the line using the `Id` property, it can never be null.

Comment: My apologies, I mean new `int` column instead of `Id`. And your method just return nulls without exceptions? Try to check what's going in your method with debugger.

Comment: I can't think of any mechanism in EF that would create `null` values in a result set. DTOs having null values in their properties is possible, of course, but an `IQueryable<OperationDto>` containing a number of nulls instead of `OperationDto` objects sounds impossible. Did you check the result of the generated SQL when run manually?

Comment: @YuriyN. Yes, the column is `int`.

Comment: @GertArnold I will check the generated SQL manually tomorrow during the day. I've forgotten about that. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @GertArnold I made other changes and it started working. I didn't get a chance to look at the SQL when it was failing. Please answer the question with your proposal, as I think that or something similar was the problem. Thanks!